# How to Merge multiple patch files?

Tags: svn, scripting, diff, patch

We use subversion and during every check-in, a script creates a patch file with all the diff. Now for the same issue/defect there could be multiple check-ins and we end up with multiple patch files. Now to see consolidated changes for an issue all the patch files have to be merged. Is there a way to do that?

Or another way to solve the same problem is: Is there a way in subversion to get the combined diff of all changes done as part of a particular comment? Eg:

Checked in with comment: "123: first changes"
Checked in with comment: "123: second set of changes"
Checked in with comment: "123: third changes"..

Is there a way to get a combined diff of all change that happened whose comment has prefix 123?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seeing a combined diff of many commits in subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466195/seeing-a-combined-diff-of-many-commits-in-subversion)

Comment: Did the changes affect unique files? Or did it affect the same source file multiple times?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[combinediff](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/patchutils/combinediff.1.en.html) from [patchutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/) can combine the diffs for you.

(Shamelessly borrowed from [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466195/seeing-a-combined-diff-of-many-commits-in-subversion).)

Comment: Combinediff only works if the second diff's context lines remain valid *after* the first diff is applied. Thus, if both diffs are against the same baseline, and they touch adjacent lines, then some changes will be rejected.

Comment: How to use combinediff, Can we use it on windows ?

Comment: Download the latest version from http://cyberelk.net/tim/data/patchutils/stable/, extract, `./configure && make && make install`, then you can run `combinediff patch1 patch2`.

Answer (score 3):

Make a new branch starting from the revision just before the first changeset.
In the new branch, merge each changeset of the issue, in order.
Take a diff between the start of the new branch and the final result.

(If you do issue-based branching, you'd get the above situation automatically).

Mercurial has a nice extension for handling collections of patches, namely the mq exension. That, in turn, is based on quilt (http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/quilt), a system designed to stack patches onto each other.