# SVN repository relocate not working with domain name

Tags: eclipse, svn

Due to frequent IP changes, I tried to relocate the SVN repository from IP to domain name. when I try this my eclipse freezes for a long time but nothing happens.

Old SVN url `svn+ssh://192.192.192.192/some/folder` - with public IP

New SVN url `svn+ssh://svn.domain.com/some/folder`  - with domain name

Note : It's pinging for `domain.com` but not for `svn.domain.com`.

Comment: Check out with your new domain ,at some other place (old dot svn folder should not their)

Comment: I need the history of old repository. Will it not affect the history?

Comment: For SVN history use this link.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282802/how-can-i-view-all-historical-changes-to-a-file-in-svn