# SVN How to search for a string in the file history?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching subversion history (full text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176/searching-subversion-history-full-text)

I'm using the TortoiseSVN and the AnkhSVN. I have a file with the > 100 changes commited. I need to find out in which revision some piece of code was deleted. All I know is the unique method name. How can I find it without digging the whole file history ?

Comment: Question closed as answered (with redirect to answer), but the other question talks about GIT not TortoiseSVN.

Comment: @ServerOverflow Only if you look at the accepted answer, the other answers do talk about SVN. Acceptance of an answer doesn't mean it is the only answer, or the best answer, just that the OP decided that was most suitable for them.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try SVN blame to solve your problem?
Also see [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176/searching-subversion-history-full-text).

Comment: Unfortunately, text that was removed in some previous revision won't be found with blame.