# Find first revision of a file containing an expression on SVN

Tags: svn

how can I find the first revision of a particular file in a SVN repo containing a certain expression ?

In this particular case I want to find the first version of a C-file containing a variable I introduced some long time ago, but well after the creation of the file.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this question will point you to the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019277/3809520

Comment: Just edit the title a litle bit.

Comment: Yes, the answer in the link works perfectly. Thanks, @royalTS .