# Finding replaced code via SVN command line

Tags: svn

In some revision, the function `foo()` was replaced with something else.  How, via SVN command line, can I find the replacement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching subversion history (full text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176/searching-subversion-history-full-text)

Comment: Close but not quite.  I don't want to search for an revision where the change includes "foo()".  I just want the revisions where "foo()" as removed

Comment: The latest change where it was mentioned, obviously? You are expected to be able to take it from here.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you know that it was once called `foo()` but you don't know the current name? That's what you want to find out? Kind of a reverse `svn blame`?

Comment: Friedrich understands my question correctly.